# Gwan handler is only accepting file requests

Tags: c, g-wan

When using the code below, the handler will not recognize non file requests (e.g. the request has to contain a file in the www folder).
With all other requests main isn't even called, and I have no idea why this is.

```
int init(int argc, char *argv[])

{
   printf("init\n");

   *(u32 *)get_env(argv, US_HANDLER_STATES) = (1L << HDL_AFTER_ACCEPT) | (1L << HDL_AFTER_READ) | (1L << HDL_BEFORE_WRITE);

   return 0;
}

void clean(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   printf("clean\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   printf("%s\n", (char *)get_env(argv, REQUEST));

   return 255;
}
```

Request: `127.0.0.1/index.html`
Prints: `GET /index.html`

Request: `127.0.0.1/favicon.ico`
Prints: `GET /favicon.ico`

Request: `127.0.0.1/index`
Prints: `N/A`

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Which version of G-wan are you using? What about your development environment? The most recent version of G-wan is known for being not compatible with many distros. If that is your case, then your best bet is either use the old G-wan 3.3, or try to match the dev environment of the G-wan team (I believe it is Ubuntu 10.04)

Comment: My bad, I'm running Ubuntu 12.10, and glibc version 2.15.  
`root@desktop-Ubuntu:~ # /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
GNU C Library (Ubuntu EGLIBC 2.15-0ubuntu20) stable release version 2.15, by Roland McGrath et al.
Compiled by GNU CC version 4.6.3 20120918 (prerelease).
Compiled on a Linux 3.5.4 system on 2012-10-04.
Available extensions:
 crypt add-on version 2.1 by Michael Glad and others
 GNU Libidn by Simon Josefsson
 Native POSIX Threads Library by Ulrich Drepper et al
 BIND-8.2.3-T5B
libc ABIs: UNIQUE IFUNC`

Answer (score 0):

Handlers get any request, valid or not, about files or otherwise.

Your handler is incorrect. Since you ask notifications *BEFORE* `HTTP` and `HTML` parsing took place:

```
   *(u32*)get_env(argv, US_HANDLER_STATES) = 
      (1L << HDL_AFTER_ACCEPT) 
    | (1L << HDL_AFTER_READ) 
    | (1L << HDL_BEFORE_WRITE);
```

...you should absolutely check that the `REQUEST` is available before displaying it with `printf()`:

```
   const char *req = (char*)get_env(argv, REQUEST);
   printf("%s\n", req ? req : "not parsed yet");
```

The code that you have posted above will crash, every single time, because the HTTP `REQUEST` value is `NULL` (not available yet) at the time the connection is `ACCEPTED`, or the request is `READ`.